# Android OnBackPressed finish()?

Tags: android

I'd like to know if it's a good idea to implement in all activities `onBackPressed()` the `finish()` function? Or it's not practical and not even good to do it?

If not, what other options besides going to manifest and input the `SingleInstance` (which I think it makes the application more slow) in every activity, do I have?

Thanks.

Comment: `onBackPressed()` automatically activity get finished till we don't override it.

Comment: SilentKiller is right, [the back stack operates as a "last in, first out"](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: @SilentKiller what do you mean till we don't override it?It calls super in it,so are you sure about what you said?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all Hardware back button itself calls `finish()` method. If you are defining `onBackPressed()` Method in your activity it means you are overriding the default behavior of backButton as `onBackPressed()` method gets called when you press back button.

Now whether to create a single instance of activity or not depends on your requirement, for e.g. splash screen can be made of a  single Instance as it will be visible only once during start of app and there is no need to keep this activity in back stack. The activity you are going to use very often should not be single Instanced otherwise a rare activity can be made a single Instance.

Go through the [Back Stack Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) for complete information.

> standard and 'singleTop' can instantiate multiple activity instances and the instance will stay in the same task.
>   For 'singleTask' or 'singleInstance', the activity class uses the singleton pattern, and that instance will be the root activity of a new task.

Comment: Some people use flags when opening Intents. It's a great way to do it? If so, which one of the flags should adapt to my needs? I don't want to open multiple activities and I often see that they stay in background..consuming memory :\

Comment: Totally depends on your requirement. By default activities stays in back stack unless you manually delete them using flag or processor kills them from back stack.

Comment: I'm trying to get the right flag in documentation, but I can't figure out. I want only the flag that clears the activity if it's already open. All I see is a flag which clear all the activities when opening a new one.

Comment: Read  android:launchMode=["multiple" | "singleTop" |
                              "singleTask" | "singleInstance"]

Comment: Now, with appcompat-v7:23.4.0 library if your appcompatactivity holds a fragments stack, super.onBackPressed() affected on fragments in backstack first: it pops last fragment. And if no fragments in backstack left - only in this case it calls finish(). So, if you want to  immediately left from you acivity - call finish() by your hands.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application requirements as we are often using finish()
but you can also manage life cycle of android .

better you use pause and resume method.